# How show data between two range of date

Tags: c#, sql, reporting, rdlc

I am trying to show some data from a database table but it showing the massage,

`"Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."`

May Query is..

```
SELECT        tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode, tblEmployeeInfo.EmpName,     tblEmployeeInfo.EmpDepart, tblEmployeeInfo.EmpDesig, tblAtData.card_no, CONVERT(varchar, 
                         CONVERT(datetime, tblAtData.d_card), 112) AS Date,     CAST(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) 
                     + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 6), 2) AS TIME) AS Entrytime, CASE WHEN (CAST(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 2) 
                     + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 6), 2) AS TIME)) 
                     > tblSettings.StOutTime THEN tblSettings.StOutTime WHEN (CAST(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) 
                     + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 6), 2) AS TIME)) <= tblSettings.StOutTime THEN (CAST(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 2) 
                     + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 6), 2) AS TIME)) END AS OutTime, DATEDIFF(hour, 
                     CAST(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) AS TIME), CAST(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 2) 
                     + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) AS TIME)) AS WH, CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(hour, CAST(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 2) 
                     + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) AS TIME), CAST(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) AS TIME)) 
                     - tblSettings.StWH) <= 0 THEN '0' WHEN (DATEDIFF(hour, CAST(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) AS TIME), 
                     CAST(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MAX(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) AS TIME)) - 8) >= 2 THEN tblSettings.StOTH END AS OT, 
                     CASE WHEN CONVERT(datetime, (CAST(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card), 4), 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(MIN(tblAtData.t_card),
                      6), 2) AS TIME))) > CONVERT(datetime, tblSettings.StEntryTime, 8) THEN 'Late' END AS ComingSate
FROM            tblEmployeeInfo INNER JOIN
                     tblAtData ON tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCardID = tblAtData.card_no INNER     JOIN
                     tblSettings ON tblSettings.StName = 'Setting'
WHERE        (tblAtData.d_card BETWEEN @sd AND @ed) AND (tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode = @cd)
GROUP BY tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode, tblEmployeeInfo.EmpName, tblEmployeeInfo.EmpDepart,     tblEmployeeInfo.EmpDesig, tblAtData.card_no, tblAtData.d_card, 
                     tblSettings.StEntryTime, tblSettings.StOTH, tblSettings.StWH,     tblSettings.StOutTime
   ORDER BY tblAtData.d_card DESC
```

And C# code is...

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(RadDatePicker1.DbSelectedDate);    
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(RadDatePicker2.DbSelectedDate);

    string st = date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

    string st1 = date1.ToString("yyyyMMdd");


    AttendanceDataSetTableAdapters.tblAtData4TableAdapter adptAtnRange = new AttendanceDataSetTableAdapters.tblAtData4TableAdapter();
    AttendanceDataSet.tblAtData4DataTable tblAtnRange = new AttendanceDataSet.tblAtData4DataTable();

    adptAtnRange.FillAllRange((tblAtnRange), st, st1, RadTextBox1.Text);

    ReportDataSource mds = new ReportDataSource("DataSetByRange", (DataTable)tblAtnRange);

    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("AttendenceByRange.rdlc");
    //this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(mds);
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(mds);
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Check all the MaxLength property of the columns in your Database Tables which you are using.
Is there any columns for which you are using nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) values ?..
If you are using such length then change it to -1 and i hope it will work for you.

or

You can avoid the error by setting the enforce Constraint property of your DataSet to False.
That is disabling the constraints property.

Comment: How can I do the first step??